# Is there a way to do a clean install of Windows 8.1 with a Windows 8 Pro upgrade key?

Tags: windows-8, installation, upgrade, windows-8.1

I may be too early with this question but here goes - I would like to do a clean install of Windows 8.1, and I have a product key for Windows 8 Pro (the boxed "upgrade" they sell retail).

The RTM bits released on MSDN and Technet and such are designed to be installed standalone but they require a key that is specific to the 8.1 bits. You can't plug in a Windows 8 key and have it work.

The RTM bits released on MSDN and Technet also refuse to allow you to install without a key so the idea of trying to plug in the Windows 8 key after the fact isn't possible, and the ei.cfg things that would work with Windows 7 don't seem to apply anymore.

It could be that a really obvious way to do this will become apparent in October but if I wanted to do a clean install of Windows 8.1 with a Windows 8 Pro key, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the generic key which is available in the `Product.ini` on the DVD (sources folder) during setup.

In Windows, [follow the old hack](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows-7/clean-install-windows-7-with-upgrade-media-128512) and use `slmgr.vbs -ipk <YOURKEY>` to install your key, change the **MediaBootInstall** from "**1**" to "**0**", run the rearm command and now try to activate Windows 8.1

Comment: There's no Product.ini in the Sources folder on the Windows 8.1 Professional media. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just found the appropriate generic key here: http://pastebin.com/cWqyYw6b